# How do i resolve the Error trying to install postgis?

Tags: postgis

On AWS Linux, I tried to install postgis by
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

However, I got this error.

> SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open extension control file
> "/usr/pgsql-13/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or
> directory

I could not find a way to resolve this... Any help?

Comment: check out this answer to a very similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108401

Comment: The problem to me is that my system is amazon linux, which linux and required yum instead of apt-get, i still could not find the "yum solution"

Comment: Hmm does it not work when you just run the same command but replace apt-get with yum?

Comment: yea... it does not work....

Comment: not too sure sorry since I've never experienced this -- the only thing I could point you to that might help would be https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/298881; you might also be able to use a script like https://gist.github.com/whyvez/8d19096712ea44ba66b0

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'm trying this script: https://gist.github.com/whyvez/8d19096712ea44ba66b0 , but i am actually working with postgresql13 to enable timescaleDb. That script is for postgresql9, I am not sure whether it will work, but I am trying...

Comment: Ehm... the script cannot work as well ... got a lot of error... it seems working with redhat actually make things a lot more difficult...